# C++ unexpected implict conversion

Tags: c++, casting

The following code compiles due to the implicit conversion for `char`.  I'm not sure why since the only implicit conversion I would expect (and expect to fail) is from `char const*` to `size_t`.

```
#include <cstddef>

struct foo
{
    int operator[](size_t i) const { return 1; }
    operator char() const { return 'a'; }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f["hello"]; // compilation error desired here
}
```

What is the implicit conversion here that allows this to compile?  If I remove `operator char` or make it `explicit` then the compile fails at the desired location.

The class that this code is extracted from really does need both the implicit conversion and the `operator[]`.  So is there a way I can prevent the behaviour without making the conversion explicit?

Comment: Have you tried adding a private `operator[](char const*)`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason that line compiles is that, with the implicit conversion, it can be reinterpreted as `'a'["hello"];`, which in turn is the same as writing `*(('a')+("hello"));` which also compiles.

Excerpt for the Standard:

> 5.2.1 Subscripting:
>
> ... The
>   expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) ...

The easiest workaround without making the conversion operator explicit is to declare the offending subscript operator as deleted:

```
struct foo
{
  operator char() const { return 'a'; }
  int operator[](size_t i) const { return 1; }

  // prevent accidental use of foo["hello"]
  int operator[](char const*) const = delete;
};
```

Comment: ...and by commutativity that is equivalent to `*(E2 + E1)` and `E2[E1]`? I wouldn't call that obvious...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, yes, `"hello"[0]` is equivalent to `0["hello"]`.

Comment: Indeed, it's not obvious. It's C++. There are books full of C++ traps and pitfalls.

Comment: Yes this is strange. So can I do std::vector<int> v; 0[v]; ? 
Or is it only with regular arrays that the syntax works? (The overload of [] in foo is a red herring here)

Comment: @CashCow Operator overload would work differently (as a method call), if you comment it out from the OP's code, it will compile just the same.

Comment: @Jerry101: And _some_ books even include them deliberately!

Comment: @CashCow: It won't work for vectors (or any classes, unless the have implicit conversions to pointer or integer types). Standard 5;3 reads: Clause 5 defines the effects of operators when applied to types for which they have not been overloaded.

Comment: I was aware of the reversible nature of `operator[]` but I had assumed that the custom operator would preclude implicit conversions on the left side.

The best workaround I've found is to declare `operator[](T*)` as deleted.  I've suggested an edit to this effect which answers my second question.  I'll accept the answer with this edit.

Comment: Should rather be: `template<class T> constexpr int operator[](T*) const {static_assert(0, "Something nefarious going on here.");}`, to block all arrays/pointers.

Comment: Yeah, in my actual code I used a template like this and deleted it (instead of the `static_assert`). I didn't want to confuse the answer by fixing more problems than I strictly asked for though.

Answer (score 0):

```
f["hello"];
```

translates to f.operator [] (index), where index is the value of the pointer pointing to "hello". In your case, it calls operator [](size_t i). Thus, is absolutely ok that compiler does not complain. In fact the index value would be a l;arge value (value of a pointer), so better be careful while overloading [] and check for upper boundary there
In fact, if you have:

```
char *c = "hello"; // c is a pointer
f[c]; // ok
```

Comment: Ummm, this is completely wrong and misleading. A `char*` is not implicitly convertible to a `size_t`, so `foo::operator[]` is never a selected.  Instead `f` is converted to a `char` so that it translates to `'a'["hello"]` which is the same as `"hello"['a']` which in ascii is `"hello"[97]`.  Please have a look at the answer which was accepted before you posted.